# Can only boot through recovery mood into fresh install :( SOS PLEASE HELP

Tags: boot

My computer has an intel cpu and a gtx 1060, after a new install , whenever i try to boot after Ubuntu i just get a black screen of different shades following each other. I can only boot via recovery mode. How can i get this to work. I really need it and i am just so frustrated

Comment: Yes that link above works - we have all been through this before - its a rite of passage - welcome aboard !

Comment: @ScottStensland: Not for me it wasn't, but my hardware was already 2 or 3 years older than the Ubuntu release that I installed. That's often the crucial part. ;-)